# Theoretically speaking, can new/init return nil in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c

Can default new/(alloc+init) return nil in objective-c?
I am finding it hard to believe that the default constructors in ObjC can ever return that value..

No memory situations maybe?

Comment: It is mostly subclasses that would do this and it is generally because initialization failed for some reason, rarely because of memory exhaustion.  Mostly, it will be the subclasses that provide initializers that take arguments where those arguments are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `init`:

> **init**
>
> Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An initialized object, or nil if an object could not be created for some reason that would not result in an exception.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> … If the new object can’t be initialized, the method should return nil. …

Conclusion: subclasses of `NSObject` can return `nil` from `init`.

Reading material:

[init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init)

[Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)